# AWK: How to extract a word between 2 commas in a certain field

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
name.com,168fcade-fc3d-425e-b67d-7176c80122f6,system,1034567,Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server, Standard (Physical or Virtual Nodes),
```

I need to extract the part between the 2 commas that start with Red Hat, or just Red so that my output is simply:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
```

I have tried with this and come close but was not able to achieve it.

```
awk 'match($0,/,[^Red]*,/) {print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}' file
```

This prints the data between the commas in the field before the one I want.

```
1034567
```

I think I am missing something simple but I cant figure it out.

Comment: Is "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server" always between 4th and 5th comma?

Comment: If you can't simply do `awk -F, '{print $5}' file` then provide **a few lines** of more truly representative sample input and expected output.

Comment: Exactly.. "awk -F, '{printf("%s"), $5}' file" is enough... However, target string must always be between 4th and 5th comma

Comment: Yes, that works Ed. Hadn't thought about that.

Comment: And yes it will always be between the 4th and 5th comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{print $5}' file
```

Also, note that when you wrote:

```
match($0,/,[^Red]*,/)
```

you were specifying a bracket expression (`[...]`) within which was a negated (`^`) character list (`Red` = `R` or `e` or `d`) repeated zero or more times. So the regexp is looking for any characters other than R, e, or d. It is NOT looking for anything related to the string "Red" which I assume is what you were trying to convey. I suspect you were trying to write this:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/,Red[^,]+,/) { print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2) }' file
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
```

Comment: I like the first answer for simplicity. In my version you corrected why do you have to move the carrot and enclose it in brackets? Why can't you just remove red from the brackets to not negate it? Like this: awk -F, 'match($0,/,^Red*,/) {print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}' file

Comment: You are quite confused about regexp syntax. `^` inside a bracket expression means "negate" but outside a bracket expression it means "start of string". Using it in the middle of a regexp `/,^.../` makes no sense as it can't match the start of a string in the middle of a string. Unlike in shell globbing, `*` in a regexp means "zero-or-more" repetitions so `Red*,` means the string `Re` followed by zero-or-more repetitions of the character `d` followed by a `,` so that only matches strings like `Re,` and `Reddddd,` but not `Red Hat` or anything similar. Read a regexp tutorial, stat ;-).

Comment: Great explanation. I will get on the regex tutorial ASAP lol :)

Answer (score 1):

If the position is not know, this also works...

```
$ awk -v RS=, '/^Red/' file

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
```